# Setting WooCommerce next/prev slider buttons to show products in Alphabetical Order

Tags: php, woocommerce

A client of mine is asking me to make all products that are shown on the next/previous buttons on single product pages to show other products in alphabetical order.

I, of course haven't been able to make that happen and i have tried a lot of codes around.

I came across the pagination.php file which looks like this:

```
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <?php
        echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
            'base'         => esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) ),
            'format'       => '',
            'add_args'     => false,
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            //'prev_text'    => '&laquo;',
            //'next_text'    => '&raquo;',
            'prev_text'    => '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            'next_text'    => '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
            'type'         => 'list',
            'end_size'     => 1,
            'mid_size'     => 1
        ) ) );
    ?>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to edit this so the products that will be shown when clicking the next button to be on alphabetical order.

Here is a screenshot to show you what i mean:
[check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4K1r.jpg)

From screenshot you will see that the next product show is something that starts with letter F when there is another product with letter A.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should hook `woocommerce_product_query` to suite your needs.

```
function my_custom_product_query( $q ){
    $q->set('orderby', 'title'); // default 'menu_order title'
    $q->set('order', 'desc'); // default 'asc'
}
```

Let me know if it works, i cannot test it right now.